# User Registration on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, membership, user-registration

I would like to enable all user to register on my website.
I checked the chekbox of "Anyone can register" on the "General Settings" on Wordpress dashboard. then I clicked on "save changes" button. For some weird reason it doesn't save changes! Do you have any idea about this issue?
Thanks in advance
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DR2wT.jpg)

Comment: ask this question to wordpress support

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the explanation.
The problem is solved. I started deactivating the plugins. I noticed that the problem is because of a plugin called "Really Simple SSL". after checking the setting of this plugin, I noticed that the option: **Disable "anyone can register"** is enabled.